# Using VLC control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, libvlc

Can any one help me with starting to use VLC control in WPF application?
At the moment I did: Added references in to my project and  Created control in XAML

XAML:

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" 
        Height="150" 
        Width="Auto" 
        Margin="10,0,10,0" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        BorderBrush="Red" >
            <pl:VlcControl x:Name="Player" />
</Border>
```

Codebehind

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     Player.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory;
 }

 private void OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs e)
 {
     var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
     var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
     if (currentDirectory == null)
        return;
     if (AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(currentAssembly.Location).ProcessorArchitecture == ProcessorArchitecture.X86)
        e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"vlslib\x86\"));
     else
        e.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"vlslib\x64\"));
 }

 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var d = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
     d.Multiselect = false;
     if (d.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
        Uri src = new Uri(d.FileName);
        Player.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Player.MediaPlayer.Play(src);
     }
 }
```

Looks like good, bud I can't see the video... I hear only the sound from video, the control shows me just nothing... What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this first when on app start

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432")))
{
    VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_X86;
    //Set the vlc plugins directory path
    VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_X86;
}
else
{
    VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
    //Set the vlc plugins directory path
    VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
}
```

So first of all you should set the dll and plugins folders. You should install VLC 2.0 or higher version. You can also try different versions of VLC

Comment: What wersion of VLC do you use?

Comment: God, I found a problem, the problem in this window property `AllowsTransparency="True"` if I set it to `True` the video doesn't shows... How can I fix it with using transparent bg in main window?

Comment: 1) try to set non-transparent background to vlccontrol container (border in your case)

Comment: 2) try to disable hardware video acceleration in vlc settings

Comment: Added setting `--nooverlay` - result nothing, `Black` background on container - result same - nothing... I don't know what to do( Maybe you know some else solution, I mean other player with API?

Comment: OMG I found solution!! Spend  fkn 2 days to find it.... Now I have this player API, really... The solution is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC
Use the WPF_D3DImage and you will be fine like me for now...

Comment: But one more problem, this soution doesn't supports opening file from resources, like: `IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/media/myVideo.mp4"));`